# How to set CheckBox in ListBox checked by default

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, checkbox

I am writing a Windows Phone 8 application. I have a ListBox bound with a class and it contains XML data. In my class there is one field named `Favorite` and I want if `Favorite` equals 0, the CheckBox should be unchecked and if it equals 1 the CheckBox should be checked.
For more info see my code below:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" Width="429" Height="621" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Margin="21,43,0,59" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="440">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Height="30" TextAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Margin="5" Height="30" TextAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Margin="5" Height="30" TextAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox1" IsChecked="False" Height="72" Foreground="Black" Margin="358,-110,22,0" BorderBrush="Black" Loaded="CheckBox1_Loaded" Checked="CheckBox1_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox1_Unchecked" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here is my code-behind file:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
List<CUST_CONT> customers = new List<CUST_CONT>();

customers = (from query in doc.Descendants("row")
             select new CUST_CONT
             {
                 Id = query.Element("Id").Value,
                 Name = query.Element("Name").Value,
                 Address = query.Element("Address").Value,
                 Favourite = (query.Element("Favourite").Value)
             }).ToList();
listBox1.DataContext = customers;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to DataBind the CheckBox based on the condition you want. Here, Try implementing this;

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" Width="429" Height="621" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,43,0,59" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedItem="{Binding}" SelectionMode="Extended">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="440">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Height="30" TextAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Margin="5" Height="30" TextAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="22" Margin="5" Height="30" TextAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>

            <StackPanel>
               <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox1" IsChecked="{Binding IsFavourite}" Height="72" Foreground="Black" Margin="358,-110,22,0" BorderBrush="Black" Loaded="CheckBox1_Loaded" Checked="CheckBox1_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox1_Unchecked" />
            </StackPanel>
       </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>    
</ListBox>
```

Then in your code;

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
List<CUST_CONT> customers = new List<CUST_CONT>();

customers = (from query in doc.Descendants("row")
            select new CUST_CONT
            {
                 Id = query.Element("Id").Value,
                 Name = query.Element("Name").Value,
                 Address = query.Element("Address").Value,
                 Favourite = (query.Element("Favourite").Value)
            }).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < customers.Count; i++)
{
    if (customers.ElementAt(i).Favourite == "0")
    {
        customers.ElementAt(i).IsFavourite = "False";
    }
    else
    {
        customers.ElementAt(i).IsFavourite = "True";
    }
}

listBox1.DataContext = customers;
```

Don't forget to add `IsFavourite` in `CUST_CONT` class

```
public class CUST_CONT
{
    public string IsFavourite { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Vyas_27, can you tell me, how to prevent chechBox.Checked event?The problem is that when I navigate to page, by default CheckBox.Checked event is fired.How to solve this?

Comment: @NiteshKothari try adding your eventHandler after the listbox is bind. i.e. remove Checked="CheckBox1_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox1_Unchecked" from your XAML and add this CheckBox1.Checked += Your Event Handler & CheckBox1.Unchecked += Aother Event Handler. CODE after the listBox1.DataContext = customers. See if this helps.

Comment: Vyas_27, but my checkBox is inside listBox, so I am unable to access it like "CheckBox1.Checked".how do I access it??Thank you so much!!

Comment: then let your code be as it is just before you start binding your listBox1 set a flag to true. and in your checked & unchecked add a condition that if the flag is true then do nothing & once the list is bind set that flag to false. See if this helps

Comment: Vyas_27, I didn't get you, where is "flag" property, I am not getting it.Thank you brother!!can you post code?

Comment: At the start of your page add; private bool isBinding { get; set; } then isBinding = true; listBox1.DataContext = customers; isBinding = false; And the code in your Checked & Unchecked Event Handlers add it in between if (!isBinding){ "ADD YOUR CODE HERE" }. When you are binding your listbox the checked and unchecked event will fire based on binding but no code will execute because isBinding is true. See if this helps.

Comment: Vyas_27, yo man.Thts rocks!!thank man,you made my day.stay blessed!!

Answer (score 1):

you have to Use `IValueConverter`

like

```
 public class YesNoToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                    if(value.ToString()=="0")
                      {
                         return false;
                      }
                    else
                     {
                        return true;
                     }
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {

            }
    }
```

in your XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
            <local:YesNoToBooleanConverter x:Key="YesNoToBooleanConverter" />
</Window.Resources>



<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Favourite,Mode="TwoWay", Converter={StaticResource YesNoToBooleanConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: Dhaval Ptel,thanks man for ur quick response, I am getting error in ConvertBack method, and also in "<local:YesNoToBooleanConverter x:Key="YesNoToBooleanConverter" />"